# is there a way to make this more efficient, iterating through rows in a data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, performance, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to iterate through the rows of my data frame and extract the values from the rows into variables and then append that into arrays. the df is very long, about 30,000.

I read online that you can use apply() however im struggling to find a way to use the function and still make the code do the same thing.

Does anyone have any other suggestions on how I can make this faster because it takes about 2 hours at the moment.

```
def get_X_y(df):

    X_pic = []
    X_stats = []
    y = []

    new_size = (256, 256) # new_size=(width, height)

    counter = 0
    #iterate over rows in dataframe

    for index,row in df.iterrows():

        counter = counter + 1
        print(counter)

        path = row['path']
        img = cv2.imread(path)
        resize_img = cv2.resize(img, new_size)
        X_pic.append(resize_img)

        stats = row[['sex_1', 'sex_2', 'age_approx', 'site_1', 'site_2', 'site_3', 'site_4', 'site_5', 'site_6']]
        X_stats.append(stats)
        
        target = row['target']
        y.append(target)

    X_pic, X_stats = np.array(X_pic).astype('float32'), np.array(X_stats).astype('float32')
    y = np.array(y).astype('float32')

    return (X_pic, X_stats), y

# Get the training data
(X_train_pic, X_train_stats), y_train = get_X_y(train_df)
(X_train_pic.shape, X_train_stats.shape), y_train.shape

# Get the val data
(X_val_pic, X_val_stats), y_val = get_X_y(val_df)
(X_val_pic.shape, X_val_stats.shape), y_val.shape
```

Comment: What is the original size of images?

Comment: @Corralien they were all different sizes, the dataset is from the ISIC melanoma dataset

Comment: You can't do really better what you already did. However, store resized image on your disk and use them rather than open and resize each image each time you run your program. You can store your data (resized images) as a single array/file of (30000, 256, 256, 3) (3 for RGB channels)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the image reading and resizing is where the most of the heavy-lifting is done, therefore using pandas `apply()` will most likely only offer minor improvements, but you can try the following to avoid the iteration:

- Create a function to process the image and use it in the apply function to create the `X_pic` data
- Combine all values into `X_stats` via simple selection
- Select the target column and assign to `y`

If you want to keep your individual selected datapoints as lists, you can do so using the [tolist()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) method.

```
new_size = (256, 256)

def resize_image(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    resize_img = cv2.resize(img, new_size)
    return resize_image

def get_X_y(df):
    X_pic = df["path"].apply(lambda x: resize_image(x)).tolist()
    X_stats = df[['sex_1', 'sex_2', 'age_approx', 'site_1', 'site_2', 'site_3', 'site_4', 'site_5', 'site_6']].values.tolist()
    y = df["target"].tolist()

    X_pic, X_stats = np.array(X_pic).astype('float32'), np.array(X_stats).astype('float32')
    y = np.array(y).astype('float32')

    return (X_pic, X_stats), y
```

If your dataset is stable and you don't need to pre-process the it with every code run, I definitely agree with what what suggested previously in the comments - run the image resizing just once, save the result and work with the pre-processed dataset directly.